# How to Login and User Persistence with React Native Firebase without load screen

Tags: firebase, react-native, redux, react-native-navigation

There are some great answers with regards to persisting and hydrating state on react-native. I'd like to persist user state in my app (logged in vs logged out), and have the app start in a different state based on the above information. The most suggested solution, results in a loading/login screen initially rendering before redirecting (which I would like to avoid).

For example, instagram/facebook will instantly load up the feed vs, having an initial loading screen to confirm whether a user is logged in.

**What's a better authentication flow for instant sign in?**

Most of the Stack Overflow suggestions suggest the following:

**Login/Loading Screen:**

```
//Sub-optimal solution which will render and show on app

componentWillMount() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
          if (user) {
            ///User login navigation logic here
            console.log('user is logged');
          } }
}
```

I am also using wix/[react-native-navigation](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/), and redux in case that might help. Just curious if anyone has some quick answers :)

Comment: I don't know any better auth flow than that. Is there a reason you want to redirect and render before authentication?

Comment: @OrthoHomeDefense Just a better UX. For instance, Facebook, Instagram, don't have a loading screen and automatically goes to the feed on app initialization. Not really sure how to accomplish this though with react native.

Comment: look into application fingerprinting. If that's what you're looking for for some better ux.